# Program compiles but I think switch is ignored.

Tags: c++

I am currently studying c++ but I fell behind a little bit, so I apologize if my question is obvious.

I have to create a program that asks for a student's name, GPA, Year of admission, and get a random 5 digit number generated for that person. The number of students will not exceed 42.

My program compiled (somehow) and I am able to get the error for invalid menu selection, however, whenever I give a valid selection (currently 1) nothing happens.

Maybe I am missing something, this is why I need help.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;




//print all the menu options
void print_menu()
{
    cout<<"\nRCNJ Registrar Menu:"<<"\n"
        <<"\n"
        <<"[1] Add a student"<<"\n"
        <<"[2] Display all students"<<"\n"
        <<"[3] Display by year"<<"\n"
        <<"[4] Display statistics"<<"\n"
        <<"[5] Quit"<<"\n";

}



//get and return the student's name
void get_name(string& student_name) //call student_name after that.
{
    cout<<"Please enter the sudent's name: ";
    cin >> student_name;
    cout<<"\n";
}

//validate and return gpa
double get_gpa()
{
    double student_gpa = 0;

        cout<<"Please enter the GPA: ";
        cin >>student_gpa;
        cout<<"\n";

            while (student_gpa > 4 || student_gpa < 0)
            {
                cout<<"Please enter a valid GPA for the student (0.00 - 4.00): ";
                cin >> student_gpa;
                cout<<"\n";
            }   

    return student_gpa;
}

//validateand return year
int get_year()
{
    int student_year = 0;

    cout<<"Please enter the year: ";
    cin >> student_year;
    cout<<"\n";

        while (student_year >2016 || student_year <1972)
        {
            cout<<"Please enter a valid year (min 1972, max 2016): ";
            cin >> student_year;
            cout<<"\n";
        }   

    return student_year;    
}

//generate the student's R#
int generate_number()
{
    int r_number;

        srand (time(NULL));
        r_number = rand() % 89999 + 10000;

    return r_number;
}


//save info. Include get_name, get_gpa, get_year
void input_new_student()
{
    string student_name;
    double student_gpa;
    int student_year;
    int r_number;

    int s_name, s_gpa, s_year, r_num;



    get_name(student_name);
    get_gpa();
    get_year();
    generate_number();


}


//display all students in the proper format
void print_all()
{

}

//get a year as selection and print all students that are the same year
void print_by_year()
{

}


//display statistics based on entered students
void print_statistics()
{

}

//validate and return the menu option selected by the user. 
//it should call print_menu defined earlier
int get_selection(int menu_choice)
{
    menu_choice = 0;

    cout<<"\n"
        <<"Selection: ";
    cin >> menu_choice;
    cout<<"\n";

        while (menu_choice > 5 || menu_choice< 1)
        {
            cout<<" Menu choice is invalid. Please re-enter (1 - 5): ";
            cin>> menu_choice;
            cout<<"\n";
        }   

    return menu_choice;
}


int main()
{
    string student_name;
    double student_gpa;
    int student_year;
    int r_number;
    int menu_choice;

    int s_name=0;
    int s_gpa=0;
    int s_year=0;
    int r_num=0;

                string nameArray[42];
            s_name++;

            double gpaArray[42];
            s_gpa++;

            int yearArray[42];
            s_year++;

            int ramapoArray[42];
            r_num++;

        print_menu();
        get_selection(menu_choice);

            switch (menu_choice)
            {
                case 1: 
                input_new_student();

                nameArray[s_name] = student_name;
                gpaArray[s_gpa] = student_gpa;
                yearArray[s_year] = student_year;
                ramapoArray[r_num] = r_number;
                break;
            }







return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Instead of trying to manage 4 separate arrays, create a `struct` and make an array of that `struct`.

Comment: *Without running it*, when I write `void f(int i) {i = 5;} int main() {int x = 7; f(x); cout << x;}` do you think it prints 5 or 7?

Comment: He means run through the code he presented on paper or in your head and predict the output value. Very important lesson you will learn. Hmmmm. Yes. Very important.

Comment: I know the type of question you are asking me, but the i did confuse me. Still, would it be 5?

Comment: I ran the question, and yeah... I am not thinking correct here.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have permission to comment, hence adding it here.
In you main(), 
        get_selection(menu_choice);
            switch (menu_choice)
You return menu_choice, but there is none to take the value, you end you using garbage value as it is uninitialized.
So two ways you can do it, either by passing the address/reference of menu_choice or by return value. try either of these it should work, though I have not gone through the rest of your program.
As suggested by others, try a debugger e.g. gdb?

Comment: Are you trying to say that inside the switch there is no way for the program to know what was the user's choice from the menu?

Comment: yes, try this
    menu_choice = get_selection();
And dont pass any parameter to get_selection()

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Now I just have to figure out if my arrays are working. Hope they are, because I tried using a struct but I am not at all familiar with it.